# 64bit windows api programming type casting problem

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, 64-bit

(Sorry for my bad English). I have 2 questions about 64bit c programming.

My code worked good but today I get error (no compiler or code analysis). And its randomly. For instance sometimes the code works sometimes it doesn't. When I open executable inside WinDbg my code always gets error. I think its 64bit type casting problem.

Code Sample:

```c
DWORD hash_string_len = 0;
hash_string_len = (DWORD)strlen(hash_string); //hash_string is 32 character hash (A998B0FE08AB295072965B5A4B0C835E)
if (hash_string_len != (DWORD)(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2)) //MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH (#define MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH 16)
{
   debug_this(); //printf("%d\n",__LINE__)
   HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, ENGINE_HASHLIST_MD5_ENTRY);
   return FALSE;
}
```

Without WinDbg code don't print error (by debug_this()) but inside WinDbg code print Line number (reason is hash_string_len != 32) but I know hash_string_len = 32 so I think its 64 bit truncation problem. Can anybody help me?

My Second question is:

Can it give me error in 64bit programming?

```
DWORD a = 0;

some_func(&a);


some_func(PDWORD pA)
{
 *pA = 1;
}
```

Because I use a lot codes like this inside my project. Like that.

LZMA Lib

```
SRes LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(CLzmaDec *p, Byte *dest, SizeT *destLen,
    const Byte *src, SizeT *srcLen, ELzmaFinishMode finishMode, ELzmaStatus *status);
```

I call this function like that.

```
DWORD destLen = 0;
PBYTE dest = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,(SIZE_T)1024);
LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(...,dest,&destLen,...)
```

So I really have function problem in 64bit programming. Thanks for reading

Comment: in your concrete code fragments no any errors. and nothing related to 64bit specific

Comment: @RbMm: "* no any errors*" Well, no. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352867/694576).

Comment: @alk - yes, not not look attentively to the last code fragment. based on second - where `some_func` take `DWORD` as parameter. if function (`LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf`) take `size_t*` as  parameter - of course wrong here pass pointer to `DWORD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SizeT` is `SIZE_T`:

> I call this function like that.
>
> ```
> DWORD destLen = 0;
> PBYTE dest = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,(SIZE_T)1024);
> LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(...,dest,&destLen,...)
> ```

Passing the address of DWORD (32bit wide on 32-bit-windows as well as on 64-bit-windows) to where the address of a `SIZE_T` (64bit wide on 64-bit-windows and 32bit wide on 32-bit-windows) is expected is bad.

<strike>Cast the `DWORD` to `SIZE_T` **before taking its address** like this:</strike>

```
LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(..., dest, &((SIZE_T) destLen), ...)
```

Introduce a temporay variable of `SIZE_T` and pass its address:

```
{
  SIZE_T s = destLen; /* The initialisation is only necessary if
                         LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf() expects a value. */
  LzmaDec_DecodeToBuf(..., dest, &s, ...);
  if (((SIZE_T) UINT_MAX) < s) {
    /* handle overflow of destLen! */
  }
  destLen = s;
}
```

More on issue migrating code from 32bit to 64bit using VC on Windows are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/common-visual-cpp-64-bit-migration-issues?view=vs-2019

Comment: Either I misunderstood you or your advice is misleading: instead of changing the type of the `destLen` variable from `DWORD` to `SIZE_T`, an explicit cast is performed. But the variable is still 32 bits long and will overflow when trying to write a 64-bit value to the passed address. I recommend that every 64-bit software developer read the following guide: [development of 64-bit C and C++ applications](https://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/).